# In bash how do I use ls to list a single folder

Tags: bash, ls

I often use `ls` (in long format: `ll`) to list a single file, just to see the attributes. How do I list a single folder, *without* expanding the content.

**Example**

```
hpek@melda:~/temp/test$ ls
file.txt folder
hpek@melda:~/temp/test$ ls file.txt 
file.txt
hpek@melda:~/temp/test$ ls folder/
content.txt
hpek@melda:~/temp/test$ ls folder
content.txt
hpek@melda:~/temp/test$
```

**Edit:**

The answer is plainly written in `man ls` : use the `-d` option. But why is `ls folder` not working?

Comment: @KurzedMetal: you are right - my question should have been: why does `ls folder` (no slash in the end) not work in the expected way?

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen `ls directory` *does* work in the expected way.  Perhaps the question should be 'why do you expect it to behave differently?'

Comment: @WilliamPursell: It turns out that it is a undocumented ( http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20051112100007372 ) feature of `cp -R` that lead me to believe that there was/is a difference between `folder` and `folder/`

Comment: That article is from 2005, i'm not getting the behaviour he describes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> How do I list a single folder, without expanding the content.

Try passing the `-d` switch.

```
cnicutar@lemon:~$ ls -ld /etc
drwxr-xr-x 144 root root 12288 May  8 18:50 /etc
```

Comment: Unjustified downvote (but the question is probably off-topic).

Comment: @KeithThompson Yeah, [Stack Overflow is not a "catch-all"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128577/183347)

Answer (score 2):

To see the attributes of a folder, use the `--directory` flag.

```
$ ls -lad /etc
drwxr-xr-x 191 root root 12288 2012-05-08 13:07 /etc
```

The -a flag isn't really necessary, but it doesn't hurt, and makes the command a little more mnemonic for me by spelling a word. That sort of thing can be very helpful in remembering certain invocations.